# Disable Stack protection for go compiled program

Tags: c, security, go, compilation

I want to disable the stack protection for my Go program. I'm trying to simulate a vulnerable C library and want to pivot into the Go code from there. However, I can't seem to find the right flags to disable the stack smashing detection.

Here is my go code:

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"

/*
#include "test.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    if (len(os.Args) >= 2){
    argsWithoutProg := os.Args[1:]
        if (argsWithoutProg[0] == "admin") {
            secret();
        }
    } else {
        regular()
    }
}

func regular() {
    fmt.Println("Go: BORING")
    C.hackme()
}

func secret() {
    fmt.Println("Go: SECRET FUNC")
}
```

and here is my c library code:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -O3 -fno-stack-protector
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void hackme();

// this function is vulnerable and is used as an entrypoint to the go part
void hackme() {
    char buf[3];
    int r;
    r = read(0, buf, 300);
    printf("C: %d bytes read. Content: %s!\n", r, buf);
    return;
}
```

I compile with `go build -a poc.go`.

As you can see, I already added some CFLAGS instructions at the beginning of my C library, but they don't seem to help. Previously I tried adding them via the `-gcflags` switch in my compilation command, but that was fruitless as well. Everytime I try to attack my program with a 300*A string, it is being detected:

```
Go: BORING
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
C: 300 bytes read. Content: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7fd263dcee97 m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610

goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime: unknown pc 0x7fd263dcee97
stack: frame={sp:0x7ffda3507600, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7ffda2d08ad0,0x7ffda3507b00)
00007ffda3507500:  00007fd200000008  00007fd200000000
00007ffda3507510:  00007ffda3507610  0000000000000003 
[...]
```

Checking the file with GDB also tells me the option is still active..
Could you please point me to some hints as to what I'm doing wrong or what flags I should use to disable this feature?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the Go cgo command documentation.

> [Command cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)
>
> [Using cgo with the go command](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Using_cgo_with_the_go_command)
>
> To use cgo write normal Go code that imports a pseudo-package "C". The
>   Go code can then refer to types such as C.size_t, variables such as
>   C.stdout, or functions such as C.putchar.
>
> If the import of "C" is immediately preceded by a comment, that
>   comment, called the preamble, is used as a header when compiling the C
>   parts of the package. For example:
>
> ```
> // #include <stdio.h>
> // #include <errno.h>
> import "C"
> ```
>
> The preamble may contain any C code, including function and variable
>   declarations and definitions. These may then be referred to from Go
>   code as though they were defined in the package "C". All names
>   declared in the preamble may be used, even if they start with a
>   lower-case letter. Exception: static variables in the preamble may not
>   be referenced from Go code; static functions are permitted.
>
> See $GOROOT/misc/cgo/stdio and $GOROOT/misc/cgo/gmp for examples. See
>   "C? Go? Cgo!" for an introduction to using cgo:
>   https://golang.org/doc/articles/c_go_cgo.html.
>
> CFLAGS, CPPFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, FFLAGS and LDFLAGS may be defined with
>   pseudo #cgo directives within these comments to tweak the behavior of
>   the C, C++ or Fortran compiler. Values defined in multiple directives
>   are concatenated together. The directive can include a list of build
>   constraints limiting its effect to systems satisfying one of the
>   constraints (see
>   https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints for details
>   about the constraint syntax). For example:
>
> ```
> // #cgo CFLAGS: -DPNG_DEBUG=1
> // #cgo amd64 386 CFLAGS: -DX86=1
> // #cgo LDFLAGS: -lpng
> // #include <png.h>
> import "C"
> ```

---

In particular:

> To use cgo write normal Go code that imports a pseudo-package "C".
>
> If the import of "C" is immediately preceded by a comment, that
>   comment, called the preamble, is used as a header when compiling the C
>   parts of the package.
>
> CFLAGS may be defined with
>   pseudo #cgo directives within these comments to tweak the behavior of
>   the C compiler.

For your example:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -O3 -fno-stack-protector
#include "test.h"
*/
import "C"
```

Output (no stack smashing detected):

```
$ go build -a poc.go && ./poc
Go: BORING
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
C: 16 bytes read. Content: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
!
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0xa41414141 pc=0xa41414141]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4bb802, 0x2a)
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/panic.go:608 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:374 +0x2ec

goroutine 1 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0x484e90, 0xc000052f38, 0x0)
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x5b fp=0xc000052f08 sp=0xc000052ed0 pc=0x403deb
main._Cfunc_hackme()
    _cgo_gotypes.go:41 +0x41 fp=0xc000052f38 sp=0xc000052f08 pc=0x484c51
main.regular()
    /home/peter/gopath/src/poc/poc.go:25 +0x62 fp=0xc000052f88 sp=0xc000052f38 pc=0x484d52
main.main()
    /home/peter/gopath/src/poc/poc.go:19 +0x65 fp=0xc000052f98 sp=0xc000052f88 pc=0x484cd5
runtime.main()
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/proc.go:201 +0x1ec fp=0xc000052fe0 sp=0xc000052f98 pc=0x42928c
runtime.goexit()
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1340 +0x1 fp=0xc000052fe8 sp=0xc000052fe0 pc=0x450cd1
$
```

`poc.go`:

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -O3 -fno-stack-protector
#include "test.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    if (len(os.Args) >= 2){
    argsWithoutProg := os.Args[1:]
        if (argsWithoutProg[0] == "admin") {
            secret();
        }
    } else {
        regular()
    }
}

func regular() {
    fmt.Println("Go: BORING")
    C.hackme()
}

func secret() {
    fmt.Println("Go: SECRET FUNC")
}
```

`test.h`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void hackme();

// this function is vulnerable and is used as an entrypoint to the go part
void hackme() {
    char buf[3];
    int r;
    r = read(0, buf, 300);
    printf("C: %d bytes read. Content: %s!\n", r, buf);
    return;
}
```

---

Without `-fno-stack-protector`:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -O3
#include "test.h"
*/
import "C"
```

Output (stack smashing detected):

```
$ go build -a poc.go && ./poc
Go: BORING
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
C: 16 bytes read. Content: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
!
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f1c5323ee97 m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610
$
```

Comment: Oh! I see, I placed the compiler flag instruction at the wrong place. I misunderstood the documentation in that regard. Thank you for the detailed answer.